# Check if a number is within a specific range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I've got a sequence of numbers - `1,2,3,4,5,....100`

The sequence is divided by groups and every one has 3 numbers in it (except the last one) - `[1,2,3] [4,5,6] ... [97,98,99] [100]`

I'm trying to find the index of a group for a specific number.

For example:

- Number 1 will have group index 0
- Number 4 will have group index 1
- Number 6 will have group index 1

What's the fastest way to find that group index, besides looping through all groups?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried dividing the number by 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is:

```
var groupNo = Math.floor((x-1)/3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the division operator:

```
y = Math.floor((x-1) / 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
GroupIndex = Ceiling(Number/3) - 1
```

Tested with all numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: 2 is not at index -1, this is wrong for most of the numbers as far as I can tell.  How did you test it?

Comment: @MooingDuck I edited my answer a couple minutes before your comment. It now works.

Comment: @MooingDuck Because it isn't: `Ceiling(1/3)-1 = Ceiling(0.33)-1 = 1-1 = 0` ... `Ceiling(2/3)-1 = Ceiling(0.66)-1 = 1-1 = 0` ... `Ceiling(100/3)-1 = Ceiling(33.33)-1 = 34-1 = 33` Maybe you are thinking about some particular Ceiling function, not about the actual mathematical meaning of it.

Comment: Whoa, no, I was thinking of Floor!  My bad.